# Python: row_type() causes error when trying to read specific columns in csv file

Tags: python, sql, csv

I am trying to use this helper function (which I found on StackOverflow) to help me read rows of a csv file, but only keeping certain columns from the original file.

```
def read_csv(file, columns, type_name="Row"):
    try:
        row_type = namedtuple(type_name, columns)
    except ValueError:
        row_type = tuple
    rows = iter(csv.reader(file))
    header = rows.next()
    mapping = [header.index(x) for x in columns]
    for row in rows:
        row = row_type(*[row[i] for i in mapping])
        yield row
```

Now the code that I have written using this function opens two files, a key file and a responses file, and grades the responses in the questions.csv in two separate categories, x and y, using the key found in the file answers.csv.

```
x = ["q1","q4","q5","q7","q9"]
y = ["q2","q3","q6","q8","q10"]

key = open('answers.csv','rU')
for row in read_csv(key, x):
   x_answers = row
   print x_answers
key.close()

key = open('answers.csv','rU')
for row in read_csv(key, y):
    y_answers = row
    print y_answers
key.close()

responses = open('questions.csv', 'rU')
for row in read_csv(responses, x):
    print row
responses.close()

responses = open('questions.csv', 'rU')
for row in read_csv(responses, y):
    print row
responses.close()
```

For now I'm just printing the extracted rows from the two files seperated into the two categories and I get this error when the program gets to the last for loop:

```
execfile("read_csv.py")
Row(q1='b', q4='c', q5='c', q7='b', q9='d')
Row(q2='d', q3='c', q6='b', q8='b', q10='b')
Row(q1='b', q4='c', q5='c', q7='c', q9='d')
Row(q1='b', q4='c', q5='c', q7='b', q9='d')
Row(q1='b', q4='c', q5='c', q7='b', q9='d')
Row(q1='b', q4='c', q5='c', q7='b', q9='d')
Row(q1='b', q4='c', q5='c', q7='b', q9='d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "read_csv.py", line 52, in <module>
        for row in read_csv(responses, US):
    File "read_csv.py", line 20, in read_csv
        row = row_type(*[row[i] for i in mapping])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why the index out of range is given because the for loop is an exact copy of the previous for loop and I made sure to reopened the file so the cursor is in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I would check len(row) and len(mapping) and ensure they're the same dimension. If they're not, you will get an index error as you're seeing. Just a thought.